Report missing import errors in VSCODE
Im properly importing classes from main program but still getting error as Import "Book" could not resolved by pylance(report missing imports). how to solve it in VSCODE?
tried by adjusting the paths in settings.json and uninstalled and reinstalled pylance but still getting error

There have been many, many questions on this topic: Import could not be resolved/could not be resolved from source Pylance in VS Code using Python 3.9.2 on Windows 10, Import "matplotlib" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource), VSCode "Import X could not be resolved" even though listed under `help('modules')`, etc. Have you read them?
